# simplyfing trigonometric expression using phase shift identities

Tags: trigonometry

I need to simplify the following trigonometric expression:

$$sin(a-\frac {3\pi}{2})cos(a-\frac {3\pi}{2})tg^{-1}(a-\frac {3\pi}{2})$$

Using the [phase shift identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity), I calculate the first factor as $-cos a$, the second, as $-sin a$. These seem to be easy, so I omit the workings.
The third goes like this:

$$tg^{-1}(a-\frac {3\pi}{2})=(-tg(\frac {3\pi}{2}-a))^{-1}=(-cota)^{-1}=-tga$$

In the end, it's

$$(-cos a)(-sin a)(-tg a) = - cos a*sin a*\frac{sin a}{cos a}= -sin^2a$$

But the textbook says the correct answer is $-cos^2a$. I guess I've erred somewhere. Give me a hint, please.

P.S. Found the source of the stray minus in my calculation:

$$sin(a-\frac {3\pi}{2})=sin(-(\frac {3\pi}{2}-a))=-sin(\frac {3\pi}{2}-a)=-(-cos a)=cos a$$

From this, the final result is $sin^2a$, which complies with the result of a calculation done using lab bhattacharjee's method and with the result of a software calculation cited in the comments by thanasissdr. There seems to be a typo in my textbook.

Comment: Mathematica gives $\sin^2(a)$ as an answer, after simplifying the initial expression.

Comment: Oh. Maybe it's a typo in the textbook then. I've just went through a calculation using @lab_bhattacharjee's inventive suggestion and its $sin^2(a)$ too.

Comment: Now I will recheck for the origin of the stray minus in my original calculation. (0:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin A\cos A(\tan A)^{-1}=\frac{\sin A\cos A}{\tan A}=\frac{\sin A\cos A}{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}=?$$

Here $A=a-\dfrac{3\pi}2$

Comment: Thank you, @lab_bhattacharjee! I overlooked this strategy. (0: The answer seems to be $sin^2(a)$.